# how can i remove variables with the value None from a set?

Tags: python

I need to create a set with positions. However some positions can have the value None (when they dont belong to the playing board). How can i remove these from my set. Or how can i determine on before hand that i dont need to add them in the set? (all the elements added are positions obtained from different functions in my code). My code so far(the remove statement does't work :Keyerror None.

```
collection = set()
collection.add((above,below,left,right,top_left,top_right,bottom_left,bottom_right))
if above == None:
    collection.remove(above)
    return collection
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up the `filter` function, or filtering in a comprehension.

Comment: That operation adds a single `tuple` to the set? Is that the intent?

Comment: @Carcigenicate no, why? That would guarantee linear performance, and you have to materialize the filter object into a set again if OP wants a set. You are trading that for average-time constant performance if you use set-operations.

Answer (score 5):

`set.add` adds a single element to the set. In your case you added a single `tuple` with all the values to the set. It doesn't matter if one of the items in the `tuple` is `None`. You should use `set.update` instead. Then there are several ways you can remove it.

```
collection = set()
collection.update((above,below,left,right,top_left,top_right,bottom_left,bottom_right))
collection.discard(None)
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - `difference_update` needs a set or sequence. But `collection.discard(None)` would work. The check is trivial but since `discard` is purpose-built for that task, I'll change it.

Comment: Yes, `.discard` seems to be the way to go. I should have said `collection.difference_update((None,))`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
collection = set()
collection.add('a')
collection.add(None)
collection
Out[501]: {None, 'a'}
#you can use the set minus operator to remove None
collection - set([None])
Out[502]: {'a'}
```